# What is the purpose of SPEC?

Tags: star-ocean-fd

When I use Crafting, I can see "SPEC 5" beside Roddick's sprite. I can't seem to see it anywhere besides the Item Creation screen. What does it do?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I sort of figured it out on my own. `SPEC` simply stands for Specialty and the number beside it is the current level of that certain Specialty.